# Is it possible to feed a VisualForce Table's var to a JavaScript as a parameter?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, pageblocktable, datatable, table

Let's say my VisualForce has a table like:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!someObjectList}" var="someObject">
     <apex:outputText value="someObject.id"  />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

(or similiar with an apex:DataTable)

and I want to make the functionality something like:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!someObjectList}" var="someObject">
     <apex:outputText value="someObject.id" onclick="doSomething(someObject)" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

As the above stands, it won't work because `someObject` does not have any value within the context of JavaScript.

Is there a good/easy way to "convert" it from a VisualForce variable (e.g. copy the entire object record, with all its fields) to a JavaScript variable without manually copying any desired values which it might contain?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it but it requires your controller to return a list of wrapper classes that have a property that provides the JSON of the SObject. (This sample code just returns one object.)

```
public class A {

    public class Wrapper {
        public SObject sob;
        public Wrapper(SObject sob) {
            this.sob = sob;
        }
        public String getJson() {
            return JSON.serialize(sob);
        }
    }

    public Wrapper w {
        get {
            return new Wrapper(new Contact(FirstName = 'John', LastName = 'Doe'));
        }
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="A">
    <apex:outputText value="Click Me" html-onclick="myfunction('{!w.json}')"/>
<script>
function myfunction(s) {
    alert(s);
    var o = JSON.parse(s);
    alert(o.FirstName);
    // Your JavaScript logic can reference any field of o it needs
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

The nested quotes seem to work OK.

Comment: Cheers.  This looked good... leaving the answer unaccepted just to see if others suggest other (maybe simpler) ways to do this.